# iif in query expression to return multiple parts

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a combobox that you can select a location, 1-7, and then a query based on that location is used as a record source for a report.  However, I also want to be able to see all...  So, I have a line of code like:

```
iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value>0,Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value,"")
```

However, I can't get it to show all if '0' is selected.  0 is the combobox value for 'All'

I understand why it won't work, I am trying to say in SQL:

```
WHERE SampleLocation = ""
```

which doesn't give me what I want.  I have tried

```
"1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7"
```

in place of the "" in the iff statement, but it still doesn't work....  any suggestions?

Comment: Your second SQL should be `WHERE SampleLocation=1 OR SampleLocation=2 ...`

Comment: If you are taking this approach then you would be better to use `In(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` or `Between 1 And 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the SQL command with VBA then it would be:

```
strSQL = "SELECT ... WHERE SampleLocation = " & _
          Iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value > 0, _
          Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value,"SampleLocation")
```

If you want to do it directly in the SQL command it would be:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE SampleLocation = iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value > 0,
                           Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value,SampleLocation)
```

In both cases you get either the specified location or all locations.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to embed the `WHERE` within the iif:

```
iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value>0," WHERE SampleLocation = " _ 
    & Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value,"")
```

although it depends how you are constructing your statement.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk wildcard character may be what you need.

```
Iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value>0,Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value,"*")
```

If that isn't the solution, then I suggest you try some variants for trouble-shooting, such as:

```
Iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value=1,"2","3")
Iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value=0,"2","3")
Iif(Forms!ReportCreator.Location.Value<>0,"2","3")
```